# Is there a way how to skip line numbers for a block of code in gcc/clang?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

I am working on a <s>static</s> runtime analysis tool which inserts some instrumentation code into each function before compiling it. The problem is due the newly inserted lines, all line numbers in compiler errors are wrong. Because I would like this tool to be as transparent as possible, the user should not be forced to read the modified file or to guess the true locations of the errors.

I am aware of `#line` but it only supports setting the line number to an absolute value and I currently do not know those numbers.

What I would like to is transfrom this

```cpp
void foo(int x){                        //line 3
    if(x % 2 == 0)                      //line 4
        std::cout << "Even argument\n"; //line 5
    else                                //line 6
        std::cout << "Odd argument\n";  //line 7
}
```

into this

```cpp
void foo(int x){                        //line 3
    {
        //Instrumentation
    }
#line ???
    if(x % 2 == 0)                      //line 4 - I want this to still be 4
        std::cout << "Even argument\n"; //line 5
    else                                //line 6
        std::cout << "Odd argument\n";  //line 7
}
```

I only managed to revert the line numbering back by one number with

```
#line __LINE__
```

which I do not even know whether it is guaranteed to work. So I theoretically can pack the instrumentation code into one line and it would work I guess. Although the end user won't read it, I will. So I would prefer not making the life too difficult for myself.

I can compute the height of the added code if it helps, but e.g.

```
#line (__LINE__ - 4)
```

does not work either because `#line` expects a positive integer.

Comment: "_due the newly inserted lines, all line numbers in compiler errors are wrong_" - What newly inserted lines? People write their code, and may run some autoformatting tool to make it look nice, then you run static analysis and compile, right?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Sorry, poor choice of words, I mean I am writing a tool analogous to `-fsanitize=...`. Not having too much specific goal for it yet, just another side-project...But that is not important really, just asking whether what I want can be done or not :)

Comment: No worryies. :) Perhaps I didn't read it through properly Couldn't you put the instrumentation blocks on already existing lines to cheat? :-) Remove comments, then add `{ instrumentation }`

Comment: Yea, I could probably, I just hoped there is some simple macro I do not know about that would save me the hassle.

Comment: Perhaps you could litter the code with `#line`s _everywhere_? At least then you'd have total control.

Comment: I think the right solution for you would be to not do it at the source code level, but to do it in a separate llvm pass. this way you don't break the source ever so slightly, and that's how all the cool kids do it anyway/it's best supported.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the #line pre-processor directive where you can specify the line.  See here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/line

Comment: Thank you, I know about it, included it in the question. But it does not allow doing arithmethic for `lineno` nor relative offsets.

Comment: Apologies, I missed that.  I think you just have to keep track of the line number and then adjust according to how many lines of instrumentation you insert.

Comment: Yea, I am afraid so. It's not like implementing `#linerelative -4` in gcc would be such hard thing, perhaps there was simply no demand to do it yet.